# /bin/sh: scripts/basic/fixdep: cannot execute binary file

Tags: android, cross-compiling

I try to build the rt73.ko linux driver for android using cross complile. I have download the android NDK and the Kernel sources of the the target system (Rockchip RK3066) and when I build the driver I am getting the following error:

> root@slax:~/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module# make
>   CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- make -C /root/kernel
>   SUBDIRS=/root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module mod-ules
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/root/kernel'   CC [M] 
>   /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.o
>   /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.c: In
>   function 'usb_rtusb_probe':
>   /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.c:1152:3:
>   warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by
>   default] /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.c:
>   In function 'usb_rtusb_disconnect':
>   /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.c:1315:2:
>   warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
>   [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
>   /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.c: In
>   function 'usb_rtusb_close':
>   /root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.c:655:1:
>   warning: the frame size of 2128 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes
>   [-Wframe-larger-than=]
>   /root/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as:
>   /usr/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by
>   /root/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as)
>   /bin/sh: scripts/basic/fixdep: cannot execute binary file make[2]: ***
>   [/root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module/rtmp_main.o] Error
>   126 make[1]: ***
>   [_module_/root/2011_0210_RT73_Linux_STA_Drv1.1.0.5/Module] Error 2
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/kernel' make: *** [all] Error 2

Could you please help me to overcome the above error?

Answer (score 0):

Although you cross compile, only the kernel can be compiled. scripts/basic/fixdep is userland program.

To overcome this, you need to use http://crosstool-ng.org/ for example.